# call a function with a specific index value of nodelist

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to call a function on specific index value of nodelist which is storing div like following :

```
var txtElem = txtdiv.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

the thing i want is that i am storing list of divisions in txtElem nodelist now i want to call a function on click event of the 3rd div stored in nodelist. The divisions are created dynamically and they don't have any id so they are not accessible by id.

Comment: I'm sure what you are looking is possible. But please give more details, or explain better

Comment: The answer is: Yes! Btw, `txtElem` is a `NodeList`, not a array.

Comment: look in here man - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ but please give more detail innit :) have a nice one! cheers

Comment: edited my question so pls vote up so that i can get back my Privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what you asked, it seems like this will do:

```
function toPseudoArray(nodeList) {
    var ar = [];
    for(var i in nodeList)
        if(nodeList[i].nextSibling) // or for that case any other way to find if this is an element
            ar.push(nodeList[i]);
    return ar;
}
```

Pass your nodeList to this function, use what it returns as an array that contains your elements, and only your elements.

By the way, you could directly call function on a specific element simply using my_fab_function(txtElem[0]); -- of course, until you don't exceed the count.

Comment: ur answer is really near to what i want pls see my updated question and guid me more about that thanx in advance

Comment: why can't u bind the divs or the parent of theirs to click events - event delegation, so u can find out which was clicked, your function will be called right?

Comment: are u talking about YUI library's event delegation ?

Comment: no. as far as i know, event delegation is simply binding an event to the parent instead of the children, so whenever a child triggers an event, the parent will get it due to event bubbling. u can then determine which element triggered the event using jquery. This helps when you have elements added and deleted on the fly...that's what $.live() uses, probably.

Comment: you can use this:
$(txtdiv).find('div').live('click', function(e) {
    /* this is the function that'll be called...if you want it to be called only a certain div, test the current element for it. if it passes, continue, else return */
});

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite unclear. Seeing the jQuery tag, these come to my mind:

A way to call a jQuery function on a specified index using [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
var n = 1; //the index you need
$(txtElem).eq(n).css('color', 'red');
```

Simple Javascript to get the DOM element:

```
var n = 1; //the index you need
var elem = txtElem[n]; //elem will hold the DOM element

//call simple DOM methods on it:
var s = elem.innerHTML;

//you can also call jQuery functions on it:
$(elem).css('color', 'red');
```

By the way `txtElem` is not an object, it is a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList), an "array-like object".